# Memory efficient way to copy an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory

So basically I'm trying to find a memory-efficient way to copy an array. Suppose we have `arr1` which contains 500000 elements of value `true`:

```
var arr1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    arr1[i] = true;
}
```

In Node.js, that occupies about 32.3 MiB (including 18.7 MiB when Node starts). Now, obviously when you make a reference to `arr1`, no memory will be allocated:

```
var arr2 = arr1;
```

Now, when I perform a copy of `arr1` into `arr2`:

```
var arr2 = arr1.concat();
```

The process occupies 36.2 MiB, so about 4 MiB.

Here's the thing: no matter what I do to empty or wipe the original array, the memory allocated to that array won't get freed or picked up by the garbage collector. Suppose I have:

```
arr1.length = 0;
delete arr1;
arr1 = undefined;

arr1 = arr2.concat();
```

Thanks to that, the process now occupies 39.8 MiB.

So what is really happening here? Is there some secret reference to the original array that Node (or whatever JS engine out there) is trying to hide from me? Here's further code:

```
arr2.length = 0;
delete arr2;
arr2 = undefined;

arr2 = arr1.concat();
```

Which will simply "empty" `arr2` so it can hold a copy of `arr1`. As you may have figured out, I'm attemping to transfer the array's contents back and forth, but now the process occupies 43.5 MiB. If this was a large array, memory intake would be huge. Is there a way to do this, taking memory efficienty into account?

Comment: Just curious, how are you profiling the memory usage?

Comment: Also how long *after* you discard the original array are you checking the memory usage? The GC may not collect it right away.

Comment: I'm simply using xfce4-taskmanager to check the memory usage. I've waited about 10 minutes with no change in the usage at all.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the garbage collection to occur?  Maybe [this article](https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/) will help you out with that.

Comment: @CathedralZealot Are you testing this in the browser console? If so, which browser.

Comment: i don't believe the GC pays as much attention to `delete` as one would hope, but for kicks, try calling delete on each element in the array -- calling it on the variable itself doesn't do anything, as far as i'm aware

Comment: Forcing the GC to run clears memory usage to 23.6 MiB. I'm testing this in a Node environment, but I believe this can be reproduced in a browser (I'm using FF). Calling delete on each element in the array clears memory to 36.7 MiB

Comment: "Calling delete on each element in the array" --- it's a nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Your profiling technique is not correct.

I created an array the same way you do and created "a clone" with the same `.concat()` method as you do, and here are the results

[image]

So as you can see it's the same array (that takes just ~2.06Mb) retained by 2 references.

The corresponding jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6o0h0r1j/

Relevant reading:

- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

To summarize: your assumptions are wrong from the very beginning.

Comment: Can we then assume that my issue does not apply in a browser environment?

Comment: @CathedralZealot I hardly doubt an array of 500k booleans would take THAT MUCH space even in an ancient version of V8. It would be helpful if you explained how exactly you profiled the heap contents.

Comment: @lispHK01 I honestly have no idea - I only profile in google chrome

Comment: `node-inspector` exposes the same profiling tools for node.